# check if new item is already exist in array typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, find

I've a class with properties:

```
id: number;
motorcycleId: number;
brand: string;
model: number;
year: string;
isDeleted: boolean;
```

Then in my component, I've a array of this model

```
motorcyclesList: MotorcycleModel[];
```

Then, I want to check if I'm adding a new motorcycle, check if it already exist in array.

```
        if (this.motorcyclesList.find(x => x.model === this.motorcycle.model && 
        x.motorcycleId === this.motorcycle.motorcycleId &&
        x.year === this.motorcycle.year)) {
        //some logic if exst
    }
```

And here I've always false.

Comment: That means the array doesn't already contain the motorcycle. You should use some() instead of find(), BTW. What is your question?

Comment: @JBNizet, motorcyclesList is not null, it contain array of motorcycles. My question is how to check if an item is already exist in array. It always give me false, but item which i'm try to add is already exist in motorcycleList.

Comment: the `find()` method doesn't return a boolean, it returns either the found element or `undefined`, which is why @JBNizet suggested to use the `some()` method instead of `find()`. Please add code to your question that will let us check things ourselves. How are you adding elements to the array? and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited based on what @JB_Nizet and @Nitzan_Tomer said:

make sure to cast `this.motorcycle.motorcycleId` and `this.motorcycle.model` to number using `+` :

```
 let exist :boolean =  this.motorcyclesList.some(x => 
      x.model === +this.motorcycle.model && 
      x.motorcycleId === +this.motorcycle.motorcycleId &&
      x.year === this.motorcycle.year
 );

// do something with exist
```